# Can I call python script within a mysql sp

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures

I would like to call a python script within a stored procedure, getting the result returned from python and assign it to a mysql variable. Is this possible? How should I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Normally, an UDF in C/C++, but you could [go this route](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sysl). I'd only advise it as a last resort though, keeping your application logic and datastore separate really helps in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The link you give is not valid any more..

Comment: Ah, sorry, there was a trailing `l`  in there for some reason: [this link works](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys)

Answer (score -2):

I have done something similar using the Python MySQL database API- **MySQLdb**. You can download it from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/). I didn't call a python script from within a stored procedure but the other way round i.e. called a stored procedure from within python and also passing the arguments to it.

Stored procedures take two types of arguments(parameters). `IN` and `OUT`. The `IN` type of argument is the input to the stored procedure while the `OUT` type of argument is the output of the stored procedure. You'll be able to understand it better with the following example.

Suppose this is my stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add(IN num1 INT, IN num2 INT, OUT add_result INT)
BEGIN
  SET add_result := num1 + num2;
END;
```

Now in the python shell you can pass two arguments to the stored procedure and get the result returned in `add_result` variable which is the third argument to the stored procedure.

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> mysql = MySQLdb.connect(user=User,passwd=Passwd,db="test_db")
>>> mysql_cursor = mysql.cursor()
>>> args = (5, 7, 0) # 0 is to hold value of the OUT argument add_result
>>> cursor.callproc('add', args)
('5', '7', 12L)
```

Elegant, isn't it? For more information about this API read these links.

[MySQLdb User's Guide](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html)

[Method MySQLCursor.callproc()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-callproc.html)

Hope this helps.